# mod rewrite: Rewrite rule mach slashes and change them to get variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using index.php as my entry script. I want to apply specific Rewrite rules to my htaccess to see my URLs in better format

For now I have succeeded to match my controller & action only by using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

So I can use any of these URLs

```
domain.com/users/user =>  /mysite/index.php?r=users/user
domain.com/contacts/contact =  /mysite/index.php?r=contacts/contact
```

I want to add some additonal get variables to my URLs, to get specific records like

```
domain.com/users/user/id/10
```

or

```
domain.com/contacts/contact/id/2/name/5
```

Now I can do this only this way:

```
domain.com/users/user&id=10 = > /mysite/index.php?r=users/user&id=10

domain.com/contacts/contact&id=2&name=5 => /mysite/index.php?r=contacts/contact&id=2&name=5
```

How can I change my Rewrite rule to support GET variables as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- QSA stands for `Query String Append` which make sure to preserve existing query string while adding new query parameters.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)